# Kafka 2.3.0 producer and consumer

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I'm new to kafka,and want to use Kafka 2.3 to implement a producer/consumer app.

1. I had download and install the Kafka 2.3 on my ubuntu server.
2. I found some code online and build it on my laptop in IDEA, But the consumer can't get any info.
3. I had checked the topic info on my server which has the topic.
4. I had use `kafka-console-consumer` to check this topic, got the topic's value successfuly, but not with my consumer.

So what's wrong with my consumer?

## Producer

```scala
package com.phitrellis.tool

import java.util.Properties
import java.util.concurrent.{Future, TimeUnit}

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer._

object MyKafkaProducer extends App {

  def createKafkaProducer(): Producer[String, String] = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "*:9092")
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("producer.type", "async")
    props.put("acks", "all")

    new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
  }

  def writeToKafka(topic: String): Unit = {
    val producer = createKafkaProducer()
    val record = new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, "key", "value22222222222")
    println("start")
    producer.send(record)
    producer.close()
    println("end")
  }

  writeToKafka("phitrellis")

}
```

## Consumer

```
package com.phitrellis.tool

import java.util
import java.util.Properties
import java.time.Duration
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer

object MyKafkaConsumer extends App {

  def createKafkaConsumer(): KafkaConsumer[String, String] = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "*:9092")
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    //    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest")
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true")
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000")
    props.put("group.id", "test")

    new KafkaConsumer[String, String](props)
  }

  def consumeFromKafka(topic: String) = {

    val consumer: KafkaConsumer[String, String] = createKafkaConsumer()
    consumer.subscribe(util.Arrays.asList(topic))
    while (true) {
      val records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(2)).asScala.iterator
      println("true")
      for (record <- records){
        print(record.value())
      }
    }
  }

  consumeFromKafka("phitrellis")

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two line in your *Consumer* code are crucial:

```
props.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest")
props.put("group.id", "test")
```

To read from beginning of the topic you have to set `auto.offset.reset` to `earliest` (`latest` cause that you skip messages produced before your Consumer started).

`group.id` is responsible for group management. If you start processing data with some `group.id` and than restart your application or start new with same `group.id` only new messages will be read.

For your *tests* I would suggest to add `auto.offset.reset` -> `earliest` and change `group.id`

```
props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
props.put("group.id", "test123")
```

**Additionally**:
You have to remember that `KafkaProducer::send` returns `Future<RecordMetadata>` and messages are sent asynchronously and if you progam finished before `Future` will finished messages might not be sent.

Answer (score 0):

There's two parts here.  The producing side, and the consumer.

You don't say anything about the producer, so we're assuming it did work.  However, did you check on the servers? You could check the kafka log files to see if there's any data on those particular topic/partitions.

On the consumer side, to validate, you should try to consume using the command-line from that same topic, to make sure the data is in there.  Look for "Kafka Consumer Console" at the following link, and follow those steps.

http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-tutorial-kafka-from-command-line/index.html

If there is data on the topic, then running that command should get you data. If it's not, then it will just "hang" because it's waiting for data to be written to the topic.

In addition, you can try producing to the same topic using those command line tools, to make sure your cluster is configured correctly, you have the right addresses and ports, that the ports are not blocked, etc.

Comment: I had use kafka-console-consumer to check this topic, and I found that have the named topic but dosen't have any data, And use kafka-console-producer to produce data,Which can see data at kafka-console-consumer console.
So is my producer can't send data to server?